# Discovering which assemblies are loading which dependencies (at runtime)

Tags: .net, assemblies, assembly-resolution, fuslogvw

What's the easiest way to discover which assembly is triggering certain dependencies to be loaded at runtime? I've got a stray reference to an old assembly somewhere, in one of the 100+ assemblies that get loaded as part of our application.

Using [FUSLOGVW](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx) I can see the old assembly being loaded - but the logs don't tell me which assembly has caused it to load. I've used [CheckASM](http://checkasm.booring.net/) which allows me to browse the dependencies of the primary assembly, and explore down the tree - but these are all fine.

So it must be an assembly that's being loaded dynamically at runtime, or a configuration file somewhere. But I can't find it for the life of me.

Was wondering if there was a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can subscribe to *AssemblyResolve* event in all app domains (if there are not too many).
ResolveEventArgs contains special field for this - [ResolveEventArgs.RequestingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.resolveeventargs.requestingassembly.aspx)

Comment: Yes, just delete the DLL to get the event to trigger.  And just look at the call stack to see how it got called.

Answer (score 1):

How about deleting (or renaming) the assembly to see if an exception is thrown at the point where the program attempts to load it? The stack trace should contain a reference to a method from the calling assembly.